# Are there published artifacts from the Shadowfell?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes, artifacts

Are there published magic artifacts with origins from the Plane of Shadow (aka the Shadowfell)?

Comment: I tried to convert your question into a fact-based one. Feel free to reject the changes if they do not agree with the original intent of the question.

Comment: Wow, thanks, my faith in nerds has been restored.

Comment: By “relic” do you mean magic artifacts? Or “just” regular ol’ magic items? Or do you mean the regular English meaning of an unusual (but non-magical) item?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie magic artifact.

Comment: Cool. I’ve clarified the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Maybe *Blackrazor*.

The introduction to the Hexblade warlock patron, found in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 55, says:

> You have made your pact with a mysterious entity from the Shadowfell -- a force that manifests in sentient magic weapons carved from the stuff of shadow. The mighty
>   sword *Blackrazor* is the most notable of these weapons, which have been spread across the multiverse over the ages.

If *Blackrazor* was carved right from the stuff of shadow by an entity from the Shadowfell, it stands to reason that *Blackrazor*'s origin *is* the Shadowfell. Statistics for *Blackrazor* are provided in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 216. And *Blackrazor* itself makes an appearance in the 5e publication

> *Tales from the Yawning Portal*, in the adventure "White Plume Mountain," p. 95.

It also shows up in older-edition sources, but I omit them because (a) your question is tagged for 5e, and (b) the Shadowfell connection appears to be a 5e concept in that it was never explicitly mentioned in any of the older sources.

Comment: @NERDmaster If you have questions about how the site works or about why voting is being done a certain way, please use [meta] instead. Thanks!

Comment: It may be worth noting that *Blackrazor* is *not* an artifact. It is a legendary sentient magic weapon. This is important for things like the *antimagic shield* spell.

Comment: Are we sure that the querent is using "artifact" in the sense of the game concept, and not simply in the quotidian sense? The phrasing "*magic* artifact" is redundant, since all artifacts (in the sense of the game concept) are magical -- which leads me to believe s/he is not being that precise.