# Are there any Shadowfell Magic Items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Are there any magic items that are distinctly from the Shadowfell?
Feywild stuff is easier to find but the Shadowfell is something entirely different. Is there anything from any previous D&D Editions?

Comment: Highly related: [Are there published artifacts from the Shadowfell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137680)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything you can find the *Shadowfell Shard*.

Tasha's Cauldron of Everything presents several shards that are connected with planes: one of them is the [Shadowfell Shard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2408242-shadowfell-shard):

> This dull, cold crystal sits heavy and leaden, saturated by the Shadowfell’s despair. As an action, you can attach the shard to a Tiny object (such as a weapon or a piece of jewelry) or detach it. It falls off if your attunement to it ends. You can use the shard as a spellcasting focus while you hold or wear it.

---

The artifact [Blackrazor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5429-blackrazor) seems to be highly connected to the Shadowfell: for more details see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/137704/63061) (credits to [Someone_Evil](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/52137/someone-evil) for having pointed out this Q&A in the comments).

Comment: You might also want to mention the https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2408226-shadowfell-brand-tattoo though the tattoos are a bit wierd

Comment: @Someone_Evil Yeah, I saw that but I am not sure about its connection with the Shadowfell, since in the description there is not any connection with that plane: the only reference is in the name...

Comment: @Eddymage The shadowfell tattoo does seem kinda useful had the PC not taken Devils Sight. I do think we need more shadowfell stuff in D&D, or a campaign in the Shadowfell. I think the only thing we have is a 3.5 or 4e sourcebook but its out of print

Comment: @ItsScottish I am not saying that it is not useful, I am saying that it does not seem so connected to the Shadowfell, despite its name. Claiming that there is a need of more stuff from the Shadowfell is your (totally legit) opinion: personally, I never felt such need.